# Customize sharethis buttons in pop up

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sharethis

I have a sharing button that use `sharethis` plugin when clicking on it, the share functionality open the pop up below

[image]

Is there anyway to customize the social media buttons inside the pop up ? and include only for example: `Email`, `Facebook`, `Twitter`, `Google plus` and `whatsapp` ?

in javascript i am calling sharethis like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({ publisher: "ur-44d656a2-b987-55b-d6ed-75f775a833b1", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false, onhover: false });</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

They actually offer that at their website.
Also you could put that plugin in a seperate html document then open it from the browser and open the source code of that page (ctrl + U) to be able to extract it as html and be able to customize it.
Cheers mate.

Comment: can you give me the link where i can do it from the website ?

Comment: sure, here it is. http://www.sharethis.com/support/customization/how-to-set-custom-buttons/

Good luck